# after consensus is achieved among n=3f+1 replicas, why client need to look at just f+1 messages with same content?

Tags: distributed-computing, consensus

I've read in many research papers that after distributed consensus is achieved among *n=3f+1* replicas, where *f* is the number of faulty replicas tolerated, the client just needs to take as the correct output the one contained in at least *f+1* messages. What happens if byzantine replicas are *f+1*? Of course consensus cannot be achieved, but the *f+1* byzantine nodes are still able to send a message to the client. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safety of the algorithm is not guaranteed when there are more than f faulty nodes. When there are f+1 or more faulty nodes, they can indeed force the client to accept arbitrary response.

The client only needs to receive f+1 responses because a non-faulty node won't proceed to commit a message unless it receives 2f+1 COMMIT messages (including its own) with the same message digest, view and sequence number. This means there is at least one "correct" response in f+1 responses the client receives because there has to be one node overlapped between any f+1 and any 2f+1 set of nodes.

For example, if there are 7 nodes and f = 2, a non-faulty node can't commit unless it receives 4 other COMMIT messages that match the same signature. Assuming the primary is non-faulty, you can't select 3 nodes (f+1) without having at least one of them being non-faulty. This means the client can't receive f+1 faulty responses.

Comment: so according to your answer, if there are f+1 faulty nodes then the client accepts the arbitrary value received from faulty nodes. However, if correct nodes respond with "null", the client would find two sets of messages: one with messages carrying the same arbitrary output value and with cardinality f+1 (from the faulty nodes), and one with messages carrying the "null" value and with cardinality 2f (from correct nodes). In this case the client would not accept any output value as there is more than one set of output messages with cardinality greater than or equal to f+1. Would it works?

Comment: Yes, the original algorithm does not specify the behavior when there are more than f faulty nodes. They can indeed force the client to accept anything. The client accepts the first response that come from f+1 nodes. So if it receives f+1 incorrect result first, it would accept that. There might be other implications that I'm not aware of but I can see two problems with what you described. First, it essentially means the client waits for all responses or at least more "null" responses than f+1 so it makes the right decision to not accept a value. That is less efficient.

Comment: Second, the non-faulty nodes are not aware of other faulty nodes. It won't know when to send out "null" value to help the clients discard incorrect results so it might as well just send a "useful" value and the client can simply pick that instead of the incorrect one.

Comment: about your first comment: you said that it is less efficient, but for sure it is more effective as it avoids the client to accept wrong values in case consensus is not achieved.

Comment: about your second comment: actually correct nodes know when consensus is not achieved because they do no find a majority value to vote for, so in this case they would send out a null value.

Comment: I suppose it's a design trade-off. I can't find an example to what you proposed (tolerating f+1 faults) that could violate safety, but it forces the client to wait for a lot more responses before it can proceed.